# Set-based way to calculate family ranges in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that contains parents and 0 or more children for each parent, with a flag indicating which records are parents. All of the members of a given family have the same parent id, and the parent always has the lowest id in a given family. Also, each child has a value associated with it. (Specifically, this is a database of emails and attachments, where each parent is an email and the children are the attachments.)

I have two fields I need to calculate:
Range = {lowest id in family} - {highest id in family}  [populated for all members]
Value-list = {delimited list of the values of each child, in id order} [only for parent]

So, given this:

```
Id | Parent| HasChildren| Value | Range | Value-list
----------------------------------------|-----------
 1 |    1  |     1      |       |       | 
 2 |    1  |     0      |  a    |       |  
 3 |    1  |     0      |  b    |       |  
 4 |    4  |     1      |       |       | 
 5 |    4  |     0      |  c    |       |  
 6 |    6  |     0      |       |       |
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
Id | Parent| HasChildren| Value | Range | Value-list
----------------------------------------|-----------
 1 |    1  |     1      |       |  1-3  |  a;b
 2 |    1  |     0      |  a    |  1-3  |  
 3 |    1  |     0      |  b    |  1-3  |  
 4 |    4  |     1      |       |  4-5  |  c
 5 |    4  |     0      |  c    |  4-5  |  
 6 |    6  |     0      |       |  6-6  |
```

How can I do this efficiently?  Ideally, I'd like to do this with just set-based logic, without cursors, or even stored procedures. Temporary tables are fine.

I'm working in T-SQL, if that makes a difference, though I'd be curious to see platform agnostic answers.

Comment: I think you're mixing up some concepts here and I'm very unsure what data you actually have to start with; and what you want calculated and how via "set-based logic" (relational databases generally always work on sets of data unless you use something like a cursor).
Are you trying to rework some existing data into the shown data? Or trying to insert new data into the existing data? What happens if Parent1 gets a new child? It would get Id 7 and thus mess up your "range"? And so on....

Comment: 1) I've edited to (hopefully) more clearly show what fields I want to compute.

Comment: 2) Yeah, by "set-based" I meant just relational statements as opposed to cursors, or logic in sprocs, ie declarative instead of imperative 3) I can't change the design, it's from a client ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [SQLFiddle Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ffd0/14) should do the job for you, however as @Allan mentioned, you might want to revise your database structure.

Using CTE's: 
   Note: my query uses `table1` as name  of Your table

```
     with cte as(
     select parent
    ,ValueList= stuff(( select ';' +isnull(t2.Value, '') 
                   from table1 t2
                   where t1.parent=t2.parent
                   order by t2.value
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

from table1 t1
group by parent
),

cte2 as (select parent
         , min(id) as firstID
         , max(id) as LastID 
         from table1 
         group by parent)

select *
,(select FirstID from cte2 t2 where t2.parent=t1.parent)+'-'+(select LastID from cte2 t2 where t2.parent=t1.parent) as [Range]
,(select ValueList from cte t2 where t1.parent=t2.parent and t1.[haschildren]='1') as [Value -List]
from table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. The only thing I'll add, just for anyone else as new to SQL as me, was that I wasn't sure how to get the info back into my original table b/c I didn't know you could update from a join.  So I made a [new fiddle solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/757ed/8) based on yours that does that.  Don't know if it's the best way, though.  It turns your last query into another cte and then uses that to update the table.